# Block additional Firestore triggers from executing in a Firestore trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to specify something like "FINAL" when you execute a Firestore trigger so an app with a lot of triggers doesn't create recursive updates?

For a simple example here is a trigger that adds the created_date field to every document that is created:

```
exports.setCreatedDate = functions.firestore
    .document('{collectionID}/{docID}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        const patch = {created_at: Date.now()};
        return change.ref.set(patch, {merge: true});
    });
```

And another trigger that does the same when a document is updated:

```
exports.setUpdatedDate = functions.firestore
    .document('{collectionID}/{docID}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const patch = {updated_at: Date.now()};
        return change.after.ref.set(patch, {merge: true});
    });
```

Is there any built in way (I have a couple hacky workarounds already) to block the update from firing after we set the created_at time?

We are moving as much of the application logic for an enterprise app that has to scale to 100 million+ records, and cascading triggers are causing huge spikes in Firestore requests.

One obvious solution is to use single triggers, then have a stack of functions that are called, but I love the simplicity of using strictly core functionality and being able to write as many isolated triggers as we like.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to specify something like "FINAL" when you execute a Firestore trigger so an app with a lot of triggers doesn't create recursive updates?

No.

> Is there any built in way (I have a couple hacky workarounds already) to block the update from firing after we set the created_at time?

No.

You will have to write code in your function to determine if the invocation should not make any more changes, and just return early.  It's common to either check to see if the change has already been made by looking at existing fields in the document.

Comment: the challenge in this case is that the triggers may be completely unrelated, so determining if an unrelated function has run couples your triggers. on the short term we are implementing the single trigger that runs multiple functions approach, putting all of the logic into that "gatekeeper". if you have seen any good examples of other approaches please share, its much appreciated!

Comment: Each problem has its own type of solution, and it sounds like you have one.

Comment: im just curious to see how other developers have approached it

Comment: If you want a general discussion, Stack Overflow isn't the right forum.  Consider posting to a discussion group instead, such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/